# Negative Margin "Wrapping"?

Tags: html, css

I am working on the site http://ezlimiteds.com/ currently. The left arrow SHOULD be in the same position as the right arrow. When trying to mirror the same thing I do with the left arrow it seems to 'wrap' it to the top when I do `margin-left: -75px`

It used to work, and then I messed something up.

The Buttons:

```
<div class="controls">
<a class="back" href="?page=<?php echo($_SESSION['page']-1) ?>"><i class="fui-arrow-left"></i></a>
<a class="next" style="float: right; margin-right: -75px;" href="?page=<?php echo($_SESSION['page']+1) ?>"><i class="fui-arrow-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

The relevant css:

```
.controls {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 99;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.container {
  width: 970px !important;
  padding-top: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: can you post your code in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The right arrow has the attribute

```
margin-right: -75px;
```

When you add the same for the left arrow, it stretches the div too far, it should work if you adjust the values lower.

```
.back {
    margin-left: -50px;
}

.next {
    margin-right: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After see the html code I find there has some proplem with your site:

1. I havs see above 10 id attributes named 'item', doesn't it's only appearing once per page for same ID?
2. HTML constructor doesn't  fit well.Float not closed good about the class attribute 'container',you will find the div.controls has 940 x 705px
3. Maybe you can just use css position(like absolute/fixed) to let the arrow position right.(If we can make it easy than why do more to confuse yourself)

And the first answer doesn't seems work right....(I means that set margin-left to -50px does't work)